# Differences between GLSL and GLSL ES 2

Tags: glsl, opengl-es-2.0

Two questions really...

1. Is GLSL ES 2 a totally separate language, or a special version of GLSL?
2. What are the differences between them, in terms of "standard library" functions, syntax and capabilities?

I am writing shaders for an application targeted at Windows, Mac and iPad and I would prefer not to have to add more versions of each shader - well simpler shaders anyway.

Comment: In addition to Nicol's answer, I've found it to be handy to look at the quick reference cards for various API versions to see if a particular function or capability is there. The OpenGL ES 2.0 one is located here, for example: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf

Answer (score 30):

> Is GLSL ES 2 a totally separate language, or a special version of GLSL?

Every version of GLSL is ultimately a "totally separate language;" some aren't even backwards compatible with previous versions. However, the ES variation of GLSL is even moreso.

Think of it as a fork of desktop GLSL. A fork of GLSL from *six versions ago*, mind you.

> What are the differences between them, in terms of "standard library" functions, syntax and capabilities?

Between which versions?

The only possible reason you could have to try to share shaders between these platforms is if you're trying to share OpenGL code between them. So you'd have to be limiting yourself to desktop OpenGL 2.1 functionality.

That means you'd be using desktop GLSL version 1.20. This is similar to GLSL ES version 1.00 (the version of GLSL is not given the same number as the matching GL version. Well, until desktop GL 3.3/4.0 and GLSL 3.30/4.00), but still different. In ES, you have a lot of precision qualifiers that desktop GLSL 1.20 doesn't handle.

The best way to handle that is to use a "preamble" shader string. See, [`glShaderSource`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glShaderSource) takes multiple shader strings, which it slaps together and compiles as one. You can take your main shader string (`main` and its various code, `attribute` definitions, `uniforms`, etc) and stick a "preamble" shader string in front of that. The preamble would be different depending on what you're compiling for.

Your ES GLSL 1.00 preamble would look like this:

```
#version 100  //Must start with a version specifier.
```

Your desktop GLSL 1.20 preamble would look like this:

```
#version 120
#define lowp
#define mediump
#define highp
```

And maybe a few other judicious `#defines`. This way, your shader can have those precision qualifiers set, and they'll just be `#define`d away when using desktop GLSL.

This is a lot like platform-neutral coding in C/C++, where you often have some platform-specific header that changes the definition and/or has `#define`s that you can condition code based on.

Comment: "Shaders that do not include a #version directive will be
 treated as targeting version 1.10. Shaders that specify #version 100 will
 be treated as targeting version 1.00 of the OpenGL ES Shading Language,
 which is a strict subset of version 1.50." From ES2 compatibility

Answer (score 0):

In Simpler terms Opengl ES ie opengl Embedded system was made to run on embedded devices like mobile phones the mobile phone system face the same problem as 90s pc that is computation issues and difference in gpu arcitecture.

- ImgTech PowerVR SGX - TBDR (TileBasedDeferred)
- ImgTech PowerVR MBX - TBDR (Fixed Function)
- ARM Mali - Tiled (small tiles)
- Qualcomm Adreno - Tiled (large tiles)
- Adreno3xx - can switch to Traditional
- glHint(GL_BINNING_CONTROL_HINT_QCOM, GL_RENDER_DIRECT_TO_FRAMEBUFFER_QCOM)
  NVIDIA Tegra - Traditional